# When does Star begin to feel this way?

Tags: svtfoe

In the show "[Star Versus the Forces of Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_vs._the_Forces_of_Evil)", we see at the end of the truth or dare episode:

**SPOILER for all those who haven't completed the second season!**

> Star has a crush on Marco, and the truth box confirms when she yells out his name.

Again in the season finale:

> Star constantly checks on the photo and the scrying spell she placed on Marco. We also see her essentially freaking out when Janna deletes the picture. This coupled with the shade of pink her wand changes to when it seems to correspond with her enhanced emotions, this fact is confirmed.

Overall we see a general leaning towards this person, but I'm curious as to the timing of it all.

> When does Star realize she has a crush on Marco?